# I2cSlave reading issue on lpc1343

Tags: i2c, lpc

I'm trying to use the lpc1343 as a i2cslave to transmit some data. Writing to the board gives no problems and works exactly as I want it.

However, reading from the board gives problems. It seems I'm not getting any data back although I am sending the right commands. Whenever I try to debug it my board just hangs and I have to reset the driver and my pc to get it running again.

Also, I made a LED go on/off whenever I try to read from it. It only does this once and whenever I try to do it again nothing happens. I think the I2c is stopped then but I have no idea why.

I have found the example code on the website once but now it seems to be gone. Does somebody have an updated I2cslave code?

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you writing code for and how can you tell that writing to the i2c chip is successful?

If the write function returns, it could be that the message has been sent but the chip is in a weird configuration that doesn't act on the message received.